# DAX Measurement YTD compare to LY YTD and count

Tags: dax, tabular

I would like to get the no of outlet on volume growth, an outlet is on volume growth if `YTD volume > Last YTD volume`.
Currently I have two measurements `[YTD Volume]` and `[Last YTD Volume]`.
How should I write the formula to get the no of outlet on volume growth

```
No of outlet on volume growth :=
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Invoice',
        [Outlet],
        "count", IF ( [YTD Volume] > [Last YTD Volume], 1, 0 )
    ),
    [count]
)
```

Comment: Could you describe your data model?

Comment: Can you show your model and the two measures you are using in the IF? Thanks.